# Rotating a sphere around another using OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, rotation, geometry

I have the following problem: I'm trying to create a solar system in OpenGL ES on Android. I already have some spheres. Now I want to make the spheres rotate in an orbit around the biggest sphere in the center (like the planets rotate around the sun). How do I do that? The rotation of a sphere around itself works, but I don't know how to make it rotate around another sphere.

Also, I have a problem with colors. There must be a problem somewhere in my code, because all my "planets" are grey. I tried to make the sun red, but it sticks to grey and I don't know why. I used gl.glColor4f and that should work, but it doesn't.

Please help, this is VERY urgent, because I need the thing running by Monday, the 28th of January, because this is a program I'm doing for my studies and I really have no idea how to fix these problems. Please help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import my.pack.graphics.primitives.Sphere;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

public class GLES06 extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView touchableGLSurfaceView;

    private final int MENU_RESET = 1, MENU_PAN = 2, MENU_ZOOM = 3;
    private final int GROUP_DEFAULT = 0, GROUP_PAN = 1, GROUP_ZOOM = 2;
    private boolean PAN = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    touchableGLSurfaceView = new TouchableGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(touchableGLSurfaceView);
    touchableGLSurfaceView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    touchableGLSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(GROUP_DEFAULT, MENU_RESET, 0, "Reset");
    menu.add(GROUP_PAN, MENU_PAN, 0, "Pan");
    menu.add(GROUP_ZOOM, MENU_ZOOM, 0, "Zoom");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (PAN) {
        menu.setGroupVisible(GROUP_PAN, false);
        menu.setGroupVisible(GROUP_ZOOM, true);
    } else {
        menu.setGroupVisible(GROUP_PAN, true);
        menu.setGroupVisible(GROUP_ZOOM, false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_RESET:
            TouchableGLSurfaceView.resetViewing();
            Toast.makeText(this, "trackball reset",               
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            touchableGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
            return true;
        case MENU_PAN:
            Toast.makeText(this, "panning activated", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PAN = true;
            TouchableGLSurfaceView.guiZoom = false;
            return true;
        case MENU_ZOOM:
            Toast.makeText(this, "zooming activated", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PAN = false;
            TouchableGLSurfaceView.guiZoom = true;
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    touchableGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    touchableGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }
 }

 // touchable GLSurfaceView with
 // an implementation of a virtual trackball rotation control
class TouchableGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private OurRenderer ourRenderer;

    static public boolean guiZoom = true;
    // possible touch states
    final static int NONE = 0;
    final static int ROTATE = 1;
    final static int ZOOM = 2;
    final static int PAN = 3;
    int touchState = NONE;

    final static float MIN_DIST = 50;
    static int oldDistance = 0;
    static int centerX = 0, centerY = 0;
    static int oldCenterX = 0, oldCenterY = 0;

    static float EYE_DISTANCE, EYE_DISTANCE_INC;
    static float PAN_X, PAN_Y, PAN_INC;
    static float CURRENT_QUATERNION[], LAST_QUATERNION[];
    static float TRANSFORM_MATRIX[];

    static int OLD_MOUSE_X, OLD_MOUSE_Y, MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED;

    static int WINDOW_W = 600;
    static int WINDOW_H = 800;

    static float zNear = 1.0f, zFar = 1000.0f;

    static {
    CURRENT_QUATERNION = new float[4];
    LAST_QUATERNION = new float[4];
    TRANSFORM_MATRIX = new float[16];
    }

    public TouchableGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ourRenderer = new OurRenderer();
    setRenderer(ourRenderer);

    ourRenderer.autoRotate=true;
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    float p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y;
    // normalize mouse positions
    p1x = (2.0f * OLD_MOUSE_X - WINDOW_W) / WINDOW_W;
    p1y = (WINDOW_H - 2.0f * OLD_MOUSE_Y) / WINDOW_H;
    p2x = (2.0f * x - WINDOW_W) / WINDOW_W;
    p2y = (WINDOW_H - 2.0f * y) / WINDOW_H;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchState = ROTATE;
            OLD_MOUSE_X = (int) x;
            OLD_MOUSE_Y = (int) y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            // secondary touch event starts: remember distance
            oldDistance = (int) calcDistance(event);
            // and midpoint
            calcMidpoint(event);
            oldCenterX = centerX;
            oldCenterY = centerY;
            if (oldDistance > MIN_DIST) {
                if (guiZoom) {
                    touchState = ZOOM;
                } else {
                    touchState = PAN;
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
            if (touchState == ROTATE) {
                // single finger rotate
                Trackball.trackball(LAST_QUATERNION, p1x, p1y, 
                                                                         p2x, p2y);
                OLD_MOUSE_X = (int) x;
                OLD_MOUSE_Y = (int) y;
                Trackball.add_quats(LAST_QUATERNION, 
                                              CURRENT_QUATERNION, CURRENT_QUATERNION);
                requestRender();
            } else if (touchState == ZOOM) {
                // double-finger zoom, zoom depends on changing 
                                       distance
                int dist = (int) calcDistance(event);
                if (dist > MIN_DIST) {
                    if (dist > oldDistance)
                    EYE_DISTANCE -= EYE_DISTANCE_INC;
                    else if (dist < oldDistance)
                    EYE_DISTANCE += EYE_DISTANCE_INC;
                    oldDistance = dist;
                    requestRender();
                }
            } else if (touchState == PAN) {
                int dist = (int) calcDistance(event);
                calcMidpoint(event);
                if (dist > MIN_DIST) {
                    if (centerX > oldCenterX)
                    PAN_X -= PAN_INC;
                    if (centerX < oldCenterX)
                    PAN_X += PAN_INC;
                    if (centerY > oldCenterY)
                    PAN_Y += PAN_INC;
                    if (centerY < oldCenterY)
                    PAN_Y -= PAN_INC;
                    oldCenterX = centerX;
                    oldCenterY = centerY;
                    requestRender();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchState = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            touchState = ROTATE;
            // update touch down location for drag event to holding finger
            switch (event.getActionIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    OLD_MOUSE_X = (int) event.getX(1);
                    OLD_MOUSE_Y = (int) event.getY(1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    OLD_MOUSE_X = (int) event.getX(0);
                    OLD_MOUSE_Y = (int) event.getY(0);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private float calcDistance(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void calcMidpoint(MotionEvent event) {
    centerX = (int) ((event.getX(0) + event.getX(1)) / 2);
    centerY = (int) ((event.getY(0) + event.getY(1)) / 2);
}

// the implementation of the renderer interface
private class OurRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    //Declaration of some variables for our planets and moons
    private Sphere sun;
    private Sphere merkur;
    private Sphere venus;
    private Sphere erde;
    private Sphere neptun;
    private Sphere uranus;
    private Sphere saturn; 
    private Sphere jupiter;

    private long milSecPerRotation=20*1000;
    private double angle=0.0f;
    private long lastTime;

    public boolean autoRotate=true;

    public OurRenderer() {

        // Defining our planets and moons

        // spheres along z-axis with lightning
        // radius: the radius of the sphere
        // slices: the number of subdivisions along the z-axis
        // stacks: the number of subdivisions around the z-axis
        sun = new Sphere(4.0f, 10, 10);
        merkur = new Sphere(0.5f, 10,10);
        venus = new Sphere(0.9f, 10,10);
        erde = new Sphere(1.0f, 10,10);
        neptun = new Sphere(1.5f, 10,10);
        uranus = new Sphere(1.5f, 10,10);
        saturn = new Sphere(2.5f, 10,10);
        jupiter = new Sphere(3.0f, 10,10);



    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // the first thing to do: clear screen and depth buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // reset modelview matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // set ambient light color
        float model_ambient[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
        ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(model_ambient.length * 4);
        bb1.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer fb1 = bb1.asFloatBuffer();
        fb1.put(model_ambient);
        fb1.position(0);
        gl.glLightModelfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, fb1);

        // set light position of LIGHT0
        float light_position[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
        ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(light_position.length * 4);
        bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer fb2 = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
        fb2.put(light_position);
        fb2.position(0);
        gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, fb2);

        // enable ligth and lighting
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

        // manipulate modelview matrix by setting viewing transformation
        gl.glTranslatef(-PAN_X, -PAN_Y, -EYE_DISTANCE);
        Trackball.build_rotmatrix(TRANSFORM_MATRIX, CURRENT_QUATERNION);
        gl.glMultMatrixf(TRANSFORM_MATRIX, 0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glColor4x(65536, 0, 0, 65536);

        // create an automatic rotation
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deltaTime = time-lastTime;
        lastTime=time;
        if (autoRotate) {
            angle = (float) (angle + 360.0 / milSecPerRotation * 
                                                                       deltaTime);
            if (angle > 360.0f)
                angle -= 360;

        }    


        //Building the planets and moons and defining position, rotation and 
                  color

        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            sun.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            merkur.draw(gl);
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            venus.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 24.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            erde.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 32.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            neptun.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            uranus.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 48.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            saturn.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 56.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef((float) angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            jupiter.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    // resize of viewport
    // set projection matrix
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float aspectRatio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 
                                                                             0.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // creation of viewport
    // initialization of some opengl features
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        //gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        resetViewing();
    }
}

// reset of view parameters
static void resetViewing() {
    EYE_DISTANCE = 0.5f;
    EYE_DISTANCE_INC = 0.5f;
    PAN_X = 0.0f;
    PAN_Y = 0.0f;
    PAN_INC = 0.1f;

    // trackball init
    Trackball.trackball(CURRENT_QUATERNION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the spheres to move like planets, rotate and then translate.

```
glPushMatrix();
  gluLookAt( ... );  // The camera transformation should affect everyone
  sun.draw(gl);

  // Draw the earth and moon
  glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( day, 0, 1, 0 );
    glTranslatef( 0, earthRadius, 0 );
    glPushMatrix();
      glRotatef( hour, 0, 1, 0 );
      earth.draw(gl);
      glTranslatef( 0, moonRadius, 0 );
      moon.draw(gl); // the moon is geostationary, so it doesn't rotate
    glPopMatrix();
  glPopMatrix();

  // Draws mars
  glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( martianDay, 0, 1, 0 );
    glTranslatef( 0, marsRadius, 0 );
    mars.draw(gl);
  glPopMatrix();

glPopMatrix();
```

This sequence of calls is often called "dependent transformations", since the actions of transformation influence transformations called later when they're inside of the same `glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix` block.

As for the color issue, it's because you have lighting enabled, and colors generated from lighting overwrite (within the OpenGL; not in your vertex arrays) passed in with the vertices.  That's not a problem in itself, but it requires more than enabling the ambient part of the light model.  Specifically, you need to specify *material properties* for your objects.  Take a look at `glMaterialf`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. The things won't move. I don't see any code errors, but it doesn't work.

Comment: But thanks for the help with the color issue, I will look at that.

Comment: Do the planets at least translate?

Comment: They are drawn at their positions, yes. Lined up like pearls in a row. And they rotate around themselves. But they don't move around the sun.

Comment: You're translating along the axis of rotation, which means the rotation really isn't having the effect you want.  If, for example, you want the planets to orbit in the XY plane, change your axis of rotation to be Z (i.e., (0, 0, 1)).